# Program not showing the values inserted in a binary search tree

Tags: c++, class, recursion, binary-search-tree, function-definition

I have tried writing a code to implement a binary search tree, however when I run my code outputs nothing and closes a program. I think my insert function is correct since I wrote cout<<"yes" at multiple places in the insert function, and to show all the nodes of the binary search tree I have used in order traversal which is done recursively inside a simple function.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node
{
public:
    int data;
    Node *right;
    Node *left;
};

void insert(Node **root_ref, int value)
{
    Node *temp = new Node();
    temp->data = value;
    temp->right = NULL;
    temp->left = NULL;
    Node *current = *root_ref;
    if (*root_ref == NULL)
    {
        *root_ref = temp;
        return;
    }
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        if ((temp->data < current->data) && (current->left == NULL))
        {
            current->left = temp;
            return;
        }
        else if ((temp->data > current->data) && (current->right == NULL))
        {
            current->right = temp;
            return;
        }
        else if ((temp->data > current->data))
        {
            current = current->right;
        }
        else
        {
            current = current->left;
        }
    }
}

void printinorder(Node *root1)
{
    printinorder(root1->left);
    cout << " " << root1->data << " ";
    printinorder(root1->right);
}

int main()
{
    Node *root = NULL;
    insert(&root, 60);
    insert(&root, 50);
    insert(&root, 70);
    insert(&root, 30);
    insert(&root, 53);
    insert(&root, 80);
    insert(&root, 65);
    printinorder(root);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running this code in your debugger?  Consider reading [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: `void printinorder(Node *root1)` should check if the root1 is a nullptr. The current code does not check.

Comment: i have chnaged printinorder(Node *root1) to void printinorder(Node *root1)
{
    if(root1 == NULL)
    {
        cout << "tree is empty";
    }
    printinorder(root1->left);
    cout << " " << root1->data << " ";
    printinorder(root1->right);
} but it does not show tree is empty nor outputs the node's data

Comment: If that does not work you will have to use your debugger. Any modern IDE should have access to a debugger where you can step through your code line by line looking at your variables and flow after each step also set breakpoints to allow you to skip over parts.

Comment: In your while loop I believe current can become null without adding your node

Comment: For debugging you probably want to start out commenting out several of your insert() calls so that you have fewer numbers in your tree. Does it work with 1 node? Does it work with 2? ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters the function `insert` can produce a memory leak when a value is added to the tree when there is already a node with the same value because in this case only this else statement can be evaluated

```
while (current != NULL)
{
    //...
    else
    {
        current = current->left;
    }
}
```

So the loop will end its iterations and nothing will be added to the tree though a node was already allocated.

The function can be written for example the following way

```
void insert( Node **root_ref, int value )
{
    Node *temp = new Node { value, nullptr, nullptr };

    while ( *root_ref != nullptr )
    {
        if ( ( *root_ref )->data < value )
        {
            root_ref = &( *root_ref )->right;
        }
        else
        {
            root_ref = &( *root_ref )->left;
        }
    }

    *root_ref = temp;
}
```

In the recursive function `printinorder`

```
void printinorder(Node *root1)
{
    printinorder(root1->left);
    cout << " " << root1->data << " ";
    printinorder(root1->right);
}
```

you are not checking whether the passed argument is equal to `nullptr`. So the function invokes undefined behavior.

The function can be written the following way

```
std::ostream & printinorder( const Node *root, std::ostream &os = std::cout )
{
    if ( root != nullptr )
    {
        printinorder( root->left, os );
        os << " " << root->data << " ";
        printinorder( root->right, os );
    }

    return os;
}
```